# three.module.js:38595 GET http://192.168.8.104:8080/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found) in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

tried to create a text loader in THREE.js and I have got an error and not the text that I created

> three.module.js:38595 GET [http://192.168.8.104:8080/[object%20Object]](http://192.168.8.104:8080/%5Bobject%20Object%5D) 404 (Not Found)

this error came and I tried my best to solve it but I couldn't get any solutions
and this is my previous question link [Text Loader is not loading in THREE.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165268/text-loader-is-not-loading-in-three-js)

```
import "./style.css";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import * as dat from "dat.gui";

import { FontLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js";
import { TextGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js";
import typefaceFont from "./fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json";

/**
 * Fonts
 */
const fontLoader = new FontLoader();

fontLoader.load(typefaceFont, (font) => {
  const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

  const textGeometry = new TextGeometry("Hello Three.js",
   {
        font: font,
        size: 0.5,
        height: 0.2,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelEnabled: true,
        bevelThickness: 0.03,
        bevelSize: 0.02,
        beveloffset: 0,
        bevelSegments: 5
    }
  );

  const text = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);
  scene.add(text);
});
/**
 * Base
 */
// Debug
const gui = new dat.GUI();

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.webgl");

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

/**
 * Textures
 */
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

/**
 * Object
 */
// const cube = new THREE.Mesh(
//     new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
//     new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
// )

//scene.add(cube)

/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
};

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  // Update sizes
  sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
  sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

  // Update camera
  camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  // Update renderer
  renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
});

/**
 * Camera
 */
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  sizes.width / sizes.height,
  0.1,
  100
);
camera.position.x = 1;
camera.position.y = 1;
camera.position.z = 2;
scene.add(camera);

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
controls.enableDamping = true;

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  canvas: canvas,
});
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));

/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock();

const tick = () => {
  const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();

  // Update controls
  controls.update();

  // Render
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  // Call tick again on the next frame
  window.requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

tick();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is right in your error.

> `http://192.168.8.104:8080/[object%20Object]`

This means you're passing an object as a URL. That can be seen with the lines...

```js
import typefaceFont from "./fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json";

fontLoader.load(typefaceFont, (font) => {
  //...
});
```

You are `import`ing a JSON file and then passing the imported value into the `load` function.

Under the assumption that you are using a bundler (webpack, rollup, parcel, etc.), the `import` brings in the data as an `Object`.

However, `load` expects a URL as a `String`.

To use the font loader correctly, remove the `import` and pass the URL string:

```js
fontLoader.load("./fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json", (font) => {
  //...
});
```

Comment: yes if i do what you say It's showing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70165268/text-loader-is-not-loading-in-three-js

Comment: I have already asked that question and no one answered yet can you please solve this @TheJim01

Comment: can you help me with doing this as I'm a beginner to THREE.js

Comment: @Azr.em It seems you are missing some fundamentals on how web works. Your other question (which you asked only 5 hours before this one) says you're getting a 404 for the JSON file, which means your URL is not referencing the correct location for it. Please do further research on how to resolve 404 errors. If you continue to have problems, add the steps you have taken to your question.

Comment: yeah brodah got that error that i have made a mistake that path of mine is wring